# href attribute empty using xpath (python3)

Tags: html, python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, href

Using chrome and xpath in python3, I try to extract the value of an "href" attribute [on this web page](http://www.allocine.fr/film/fichefilm_gen_cfilm=231874.html). "href" attributes contains the link to the movie's trailer ("bande-annonce" in french) I am interested in.

[image: Here is the html of the page, with the href I want in the <a> tag (highlighted in blue)]

First thing, using xpath, it appears that the "a" tag is a "span" tag. In fact, using this code:

```
response_main=urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.allocine.fr/film/fichefilm_gen_cfilm=231874.html")
htmlparser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree_main = etree.parse(response_main, htmlparser)
tree_main.xpath('//*[@id=\"content-start\"]/article/section[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/*')
```

I get this result:

```
[<Element span at 0x111f70c08>]
```

So the "div" tag contains no "a" tag but just a "span" tag. I've read that html visualization in browsers doesn't always reflects the "real" html sent by the server. Thus I tried to use this command to extract the href:

```
    response_main=urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.allocine.fr/film/fichefilm_gen_cfilm=231874.html")
htmlparser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree_main = etree.parse(response_main, htmlparser)
tree_main.xpath('//*[@id=\"content-start\"]/article/section[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/span/@href')
```

Unfortunately, this returns nothing... And when I check the attributes within the "span" tag with this command:

```
tree_main.xpath('//*[@id=\"content-start\"]/article/section[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/span/@*')
```

I got the value of the "class" attribute, but nothing about "href"... :

```
['ACrL3ZACrpZGVvL3BsYXllcl9nZW5fY21lZGlhPTE5NTYwMDcyJmNmaWxtPTIzMTg3NC5odG1s meta-title-link']
```

I'd like some help to understand what's happening here. Why the "a" tag is a "span" tag? And the most important question to me, how can I extract the value of the "href" attribute?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Required link generated dynamically with `JavaScript`. With `urllib.request` you can get only initial `HTML` page source while you need `HTML` after all `JavaScript` been executed.

You might use [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) + [`chromedriver`](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.28/) to get dynamically generated content:

```
from selenium import webdriver as web
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait 

driver = web.Chrome("/path/to/chromedriver")
driver.get("http://www.allocine.fr/film/fichefilm_gen_cfilm=231874.html")
link = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='meta-title']/a[@class='xXx meta-title-link']")))
print(link.get_attribute('href'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips @Andersson I am using Anaconda and Spyder to code in python3. So I've added selenium 3.3.1 and chromedriver 2.24.1 to Anaconda.

Comment: One last question! Each time I use this command: drive = web.chrome() , a chrome browser opens. Would you know a way to close it after the print of href? (with a command line for sure)
I am afraid it might be a problem if this command is used many times :)

Comment: You can use `driver.close()` to close currently opened browser window or `driver.quit()` to close browser and stop `chromedriver`